# Limit problem with sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let us consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ as follows:
$$a_n= \log_{2n}(2n+1)\log_{2n+2}(2n+3)\log_{2n+4}(2n+5) \dots\log_{4n^2}(4n^2+1).$$ Compute the limit of this sequence.

Comment: Why the total lack of context? After 20 questions asked, one would expect you know better...

Comment: How can I prove it?

Comment: I have no idea how to start.

Comment: $\log_y(x)=\log(x)/\log(y)$ seems to be a pretty useful reformaultion

Comment: Numerically, the result is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Correct. See my answer.

Comment: Another "missing context" closure. As far as I am concerned, a good question needs no context. I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
a_n
&= \log_{2n}(2n+1)\log_{2n+2}(2n+3)\log_{2n+4}(2n+5) \dots\log_{4n^2}(4n^2+1)\\
&= \prod_{k=n}^{2n^2}\log_{2k}(2k+1)\\
&= \prod_{k=n}^{2n^2}\frac{\ln(2k+1)}{\ln(2k)}\\
&= \prod_{k=n}^{2n^2}\frac{\ln(2k)+\ln(1+1/(2k))}{\ln(2k)}\\
&= \prod_{k=n}^{2n^2}(1+\frac{\ln(1+1/(2k))}{\ln(2k)})\\
\text{so}\\
\ln(a_n)
&= \sum_{k=n}^{2n^2}\ln(1+\frac{\ln(1+1/(2k))}{\ln(2k)})\\
&= \sum_{k=n}^{2n^2}\ln(1+\frac{1/(2k)+O(1/k^2))}{\ln(2k)})\\
&= \sum_{k=n}^{2n^2}\ln(1+\frac{1}{2k\ln(2k)}+O(\frac1{\ln(k)k^2}))\\
&= \sum_{k=n}^{2n^2}(\frac{1}{2k\ln(2k)}+O(\frac1{\ln(k)k^2}))\\
& \approx \frac12\ln\ln(2k)|_{k=n}^{2n^2}+O(\frac1{\ln(n)})\\
&= \frac12(\ln\ln(4n^2)-\ln\ln(2n))+O(\frac1{\ln(n)})\\
&= \frac12\ln(\frac{\ln(4n^2)}{\ln(2n)})+O(\frac1{\ln(n)})\\
&= \frac12\ln(\frac{2\ln(n)+2\ln(2)}{\ln(n)+\ln(2)})+O(\frac1{\ln(n)})\\
&= \frac12\ln(2)+O(\frac1{\ln(n)})\\
&\to \frac12\ln(2)\\
\text{so}\\
a_n
&\to \sqrt{2}\\
\end{array}
$